# Selecting all links except hovered one CSS only

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to make a CSS selector that matches all links except the hovered one.
Naturally I though of using the `~` operator to catch around elements:

```
a:hover ~a
```

This works fine but it only matches elements after the hovered one, and I would like to get the ones before as well. So I though of using this:

```
a:hover ~a,  a ~a:hover
```

But no success.

---

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ELA8b/) that shows what I am talking about.
Of course I know I could do it easily with jQuery but I like to exploit CSS as much as possible when I think javascript can be avoided.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cant do what you are explicitly after, without using JavaScript due to the way CSS selectors work based on DOM hierarchy and their limited potential for traversal.

However, given what I imagine you are trying to achieve, why not apply the hover to the parent element and exclude the currently hovered `a`?

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ELA8b/1/)

[(and an alternative)](http://jsfiddle.net/ELA8b/2/)

```
div:hover a:not(:hover){
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Then you may need [to add](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/ELA8b/3/) `display: inline-block;` to the wrapper `<div>`

Comment: Well that is exactly what I am asking for. Thank you!. I will gladly accept this answer when the 15 minutes will be passed.

Comment: This won't work if there are other links nested in an other element http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ELA8b/4/

Comment: This may be what was intended, but it does not answer the question actually asked. The selector does not match any links unless a `div` element is hovered, so it does not match “all links except the hovered one”.

Comment: This also behaves somewhat oddly, since the behavior depends on whether an enclosing `div` is hovered, not just which link, if any, is hovered.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - absolutely, and in the absence of proposed alternatives not using JS- and bearing in mind this answers the intended question, I've amended the answer text to make clear the limitations previously assumed to be understood.

Comment: What the question is *explicitly* after is “CSS selector that matches all links except the hovered one”, and *that* question has a CSS answer.

Answer (score 2):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/ELA8b/6/)** (with green and red color)

css

```
a {
    color: #f00;
}
div {
    display: inline-block;
}

#scope1:hover > a, #scope2:hover > a{
       color : #0f0; 
}
#scope1 a:hover, #scope2 a:hover {
       color : #f00 ; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following selector matches all links except a hovered link:

```
a[href]:not(:hover)
```

When no link is hovered, this matches all links, which logically satisfies the requirement.

Note that `a` matches all `a` elements, including `<a name=...>...</a>` (outdated, but works) and `<a>...</a>` (valid, mentioned in HTML5 specs). Using `a[href]` restricts us to `a` elements that have `href` attribute, i.e. to links.

If you actually meant to ask for a selector that matches all links except a hovered link *if* there is a hovered link and no element otherwise, then there is no CSS solution (but there are JavaScript solutions).